# How to reverse the row -column from data table and display in to gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a datatable named `test` which contains values as shown below

```
Firstname  Lastname   Age   Location
Sasi       verpal     30    Veega
```

I want to show it in gridview as shown below

```
Firstname    sasi
Lastname    verpal  
Age           30    
Location     Veega
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: see this- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Rotate-DataTable---Convert-GridView-Columns-to-Rows-and-Rows-to-Columns-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: @Khairul Islam i used that one ,but i am getting Column1 and Column2, ,how to remove it.rest all rows looks okey,but these two columns annoyin me

Comment: i hide it in row created event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by moving the column name and value to a different structure (class) and then binding a list of that class to your grid.

```
void Main()
{   
    List<DisplayColumn> dataList = new List<DisplayColumn>();
    dataList.Add(new DisplayColumn("Firstname", "Sasi"));
    dataList.Add(new DisplayColumn("Lastname", "verpal"));
    dataList.Add(new DisplayColumn("Age", "30"));
    dataList.Add(new DisplayColumn("Location", "Veega"));

    // However, in your case you can add the values using
    foreach (var column in myTable.Rows[0].Columns)
    {
        dataList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(column.Name, column.Value.ToString()));
    }

    // Now bind the dataList to your grid
}

public class DisplayColumn
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }

    public DisplayColumn(string columnName, string columnValue)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        ColumnValue = columnName;
    }
}
```